# DosBox on Windows Phone 7 and Android?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, emulation

Is there any port of DosBox on Windows Phone 7 and Android?

If not is it any good VM of any old hardware (QNX, DOS (DJGPP, Watcom), Amiga) for both Windows Phone 7 and Android?

Basically I am trying to emulate my own game written in Allegro 4.2.3 on both Windows Phone 7 and Android.

Comment: Not answering? :) Oh well. Closed in, 3, 2...

Comment: a simple google search for: DosBox Android yeilds this: http://androiddosbox.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about WinPhone7, but I do know that [android does have a DOSBox port in progress.](http://androiddosbox.appspot.com/)

I've never used it personally (as it requires a hardware keyboard, and my current phone lacks one), but I've heard from others that it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that DOS was written for the x86 CPU, and few mobile devices use an x86 CPU. Most Android phones use ARM CPUs, and I imagine that Windows Phone is the same. You would either need to rewrite DOS and whatever "Allegro 4.2.3" is and your app to run on ARM, or run an x86 emulator on ARM and try to get all that code to run in the emulator. I am not aware of any x86 emulators that will run on Android or Windows Phone devices.